# How to display params from a different Model within the /show of a different Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Working on an app in rails 4 that has **Invoices** and **Clients** as Models - I already set the associations between them as you can see in the snippets below from both Models, but can't achieve how to display for instance the Client.name within an Invoice show view.

Through Rails console, if I do 'Invoice.last.client.name' - I can see the client name - but once I try to show that same thing in the view with this piece of code:

```
  <% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
    <%= invoice.client.name %>
  <% end %>
```

I get this error **undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass**

Invoice.rb (Model)

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  acts_as_schedulable :schedule

  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :clients

end
```

Client.rb (Model)

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
  validates_formatting_of :email, using: :email
end
```

Tried adding doing something with nested attributes and adding the 'name' method in the Invoice controller, but don't know what I'm doing wrong. For more reference, I have included the whole Invoice controller in [this pastebin link.](http://pastebin.com/s0hAXqgu)

```
  def name
    @invoice = Invoice.client.name
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you have an Invoice instant without a client. I would start by confirming in the console that all the Invoices have a client e.g.

```
Invoice.all.reject{|invoice| invoice.client}.count
```

If the answer is not zero, that's your problem.

Also the name method you've posted is incorrect and would throw an error. You're calling a class method 'client' on the Invoice class.